# Why This inline block is not centering?

Tags: css

[Check this out](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwWWOy) I tried to center this inline-block but it is not working :( . I read couple of answer about similar issue but the solution; adding width and centering text is not working. Bellow is the codes. above is the codepen.

HTML:

```css
body {
  background: #34495e;
  padding: 50px 0px;
}
.left.end {
  border-bottom: 8px solid #8e44ad;
}
.right.end {
  border-bottom: 8px solid #d35400;
}
.container {
  background: #ecf0f1;
  min-height: 480px;
  width: 700px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
.container h1 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.right,
.left {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  Font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.left {
  width: 20%;
  background: #2c3e50;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #34495e;
}
.right {
  width: 80%;
  background: #16a085;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1abc9c;
}
.hright,
.hleft {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.hleft {
  width: 20%;
  background: #c0392b;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e74c3c;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
.hright {
  width: 80%;
  background: #27ae60;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2ecc71;
  padding-left: 10px;
  line-height: 100px
}
.download {
  width: 220px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px auto;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4;
  -moz-border-radius: 4;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px #000000;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px #000000;
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #2980b9;
  padding: 25px 30px 25px 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.download a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.footer {
  text-align: justify;
  padding: 16px;
  background: #2c3e50;
  color: #7f8c8d;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="hleft">Back</div>
  <div class="hright">
    <h1>Drive Nuts</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="left">Size</div>
  <div class="right">ID</div>

  <div class="left">ID</div>
  <div class="right">Datas</div>

  <div class="left end">Hits</div>
  <div class="right end">Datas</div>

  <div class="download"><a href="">DOWNLOAD NOW</a>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which one is supposed to be centered?

Comment: There are only one inline blog. the link. .download class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for `text-align` to work you need to specify it on a container, that container, in turn, will have centered text. Right now you have set `text-align: center` on the actual element you want centered.

EDIT:

Sample css:

```
.download {
  text-align: center;
}
.download a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 220px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4;
  -moz-border-radius: 4;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px #000000;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px #000000;
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #2980b9;
  padding: 25px 30px 25px 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

This makes it so your `.download`-element works as awrapper telling everyting inside it to be centered. Than it applies your styling of the button to the `<a/>`-tag only.

EDIT 2:

For everyone recommending additional wrapper divs. Please don't. The link already has a wrapper and this HTML has the correct amount of elements (I would even argue one too many). It still has about 100% too many css-classes...

Unrelated to the question: This layout really looks like a table. No point in avoiding the `<table/>`-tag if the content is actually supposed to be a table of data.

Comment: I don't get that... In above code, which tag I have to centralizer?

Comment: a new div element that's wrapped around your download div.

Comment: Any way without adding another div? (All following messages bellow says same thing.

Comment: I edited my answer, just move most of your css to the `.download a` selector instead.

Comment: Thank you. Just help me a little more... margin-top of .download is not working :( http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azpdEj

Comment: `margin` is the space that is added to the outside of the elements. In this case it makes sense to set the margin of the `<a>`-tag.

Answer (score 2):

[Updated code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ByppYM)

Give `text-align: center` to a parent element.

**HTML**

```
<div class="center">
    <div class="download"><a href="">DOWNLOAD NOW</a></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.center {
  text-align: center
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your download button in a container, and give the container the

```
text-align:center;
```

property:

```css
body {
  background: #34495e;
  padding: 50px 0px;
}
.left.end {
  border-bottom: 8px solid #8e44ad;
}
.right.end {
  border-bottom: 8px solid #d35400;
}
.container {
  background: #ecf0f1;
  min-height: 480px;
  width: 700px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;

}
.container h1 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.right,
.left {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  Font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.left {
  width: 20%;
  background: #2c3e50;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #34495e;
}
.right {
  width: 80%;
  background: #16a085;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1abc9c;
}
.hright,
.hleft {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.hleft {
  width: 20%;
  background: #c0392b;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e74c3c;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
.hright {
  width: 80%;
  background: #27ae60;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2ecc71;
  padding-left: 10px;
  line-height: 100px
}
.download {
  width: 220px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px auto;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4;
  -moz-border-radius: 4;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px #000000;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px #000000;
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #2980b9;
  padding: 25px 30px 25px 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.download a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.footer {
  text-align: justify;
  padding: 16px;
  background: #2c3e50;
  color: #7f8c8d;
}
.download-container{
    text-align:center;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="hleft">Back</div>
  <div class="hright">
    <h1>Drive Nuts</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="left">Size</div>
  <div class="right">ID</div>

  <div class="left">ID</div>
  <div class="right">Datas</div>

  <div class="left end">Hits</div>
  <div class="right end">Datas</div>
<div class="download-container">
  <div class="download"><a href="">DOWNLOAD NOW</a>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```